# Issue in IE8 with display of web page using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is the code which works fine in IE9 and above but not working fine in IE8

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="div1"> 
                        <div class="panel panel-default" style="" id="panel1">
                            <div class="panel-body" style="" id="panelbody1">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <img src="img/Data Input.png" class="img-responsive" style="float:right;"/>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="">
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xl1">Data Input Interface</button>
                                  </div>  
                            </div>      
                            <div class="panel-body" style="" id="panelbody2">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <img src="img/Dashboard.png" class="img-responsive" style="float:right;"/>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xl2">Dashboard</button>
                                  </div>  
                            </div>      
                      </div>   


<!--CSS File -->

<style>
@media(min-width:1500px){


.btn-xl1 {
       padding:40px;
        font-size: 25px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin-left:20px;
         color:green;
        background-color:lightgrey;
        width:100%;

      }

      .btn-xl2 {

          padding: 40px;
        font-size: 25px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin-left:20px;
       color:green;
        background-color:lightgrey;
        width:100%;
      }

    .btn-xl1 img{width:60px;}
    .btn-xl2 img{width:60px;}      
#panel1{width:70%;}
#panelbody1{border:1px lightgrey solid; border-radius:10px;}
#panelbody2{border:1px solid lightgrey;  border-radius:10px; margin-top:10px;}
#panelbody1 img{padding-top:10px;}
#panelbody2 img{padding-top:30px;}

}
</style>
```

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
```

The problem with the IE8 which I faced was the alignment of button, css, background-color etc cant be seen although I have included all the necessary files. what is the issue????

Comment: Have you checked all the caveats and advice in the README?: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>` is called after all the body content.
2. For IE8 and below, you must run your HTML script from a server in order to avoid a security error caused by respond.js / respond.min.js. If you haven't organized a server, you can Debug via localhost and this will fix your issue.

Further information can be seen [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2173441)

Comment: I tried but not working!!!

Comment: Have you tried using respond.js instead of respond.min.js?

Comment: yes i tried with that also but still not working.